# Override Read and Write of Property of base class

Tags: delphi

I want to create a new component which behaves exactly like a TEdit, but has some characters replaced of the text that is entered in it.
For Example, when someone types 'abc' into the new component, I want the Text-Property to return 'aac', when it is read in the source code.

```
type
  TMyEdit = class(TEdit)
  public
    property Text : TCaption read GetText;
  end;
```

Something like this.

Is it possible to override an existing property with a new read - function for this property and not change the write - function for this property?

Regards

Comment: It is VCL of Delphi XE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before  :

> The best approach is to use TMaskEdit

But if you realy want to implement the behaviour  then it could be done like this:

```
type
  TMyEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    function GetText: TCaption;
    procedure SetText(const Value: TCaption);
  public
    property Text: TCaption read GetText write SetText;
  end;

{ TMyEdit }

function TMyEdit.GetText: TCaption;
begin
  Result := 'TMyEdit' + inherited Text;
end;

procedure TMyEdit.SetText(const Value: TCaption);
begin
  inherited Text := Value;
end;
```

So in short I create both `GetText` and `SetText` settext just call the inherited Text property while GetText changes the result

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your proposal. However, if I try to read Text from this component I get a whole lot of access violations. Do you happen to know what the problem is?

Comment: Yes. I've made a bug. It should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
TMyEdit = class(TEdit)
protected
   procedure Change; override;
 end;

procedure TMyEdit.Change;
begin
  Self.Text := StringReplace(Self.Text, 'aaa', 'ccc');
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: However the best approach is to use TMaskEdit

Comment: I don't think that this is what the question asks for. I got it as that OP wants to get text different from what is set from the `Text` property. You are modifying that property.